# How to solve must update certificate to sign and install app in real device using flutter?

Tags: flutter

This error display when run on real device and i updated my certificate :-

The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.

Comment: Error 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0) this message display when run from vcode

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that you must update the certificate. As you still get the error, the best guess is you did not do it correctly. The next step would be to tell us what you *did* do, so we can compare.